# TFS wit field width different in VS2015 and Web UI

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have a set of custom controls on work items. (The server is on-prem TFS 2015)
The definition of the group is:

```
<Column PercentWidth="100">
    <Control FieldName="System.AssignedTo" Type="FieldControl" Label="Assi&amp;gned To" LabelPosition="Left" />
    <Control Type="LabelControl" Label="State Order : 1.New 2.Approved 3.Committed 4.Done 5.Removed" LabelPosition="Left" />
    <Control FieldName="System.State" Type="FieldControl" Label="Stat&amp;e" LabelPosition="Left" />
    <Control FieldName="System.Reason" Type="FieldControl" Label="Reason" LabelPosition="Left" ReadOnly="True" />
      <Group>
        <Column PercentWidth="8">
           <Control Type="LabelControl" Label="Release #" LabelPosition="Left" />
        </Column>
        <Column PercentWidth="5">
          <Control FieldName="MyCompany.ReleaseYear" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" />
        </Column>
        <Column PercentWidth="5">
           <Control FieldName="MyCompany.MajorRelease" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" />
        </Column>
        <Column PercentWidth="5">
          <Control FieldName="MyCompany.MinorRelease" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" />
        </Column>
        <Column PercentWidth="5">
          <Control FieldName="MyCompany.HotfixRelease" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" />
        </Column>
        <Column PercentWidth="25">
          <Control FieldName="MyCompany.HotfixSeverity" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" />
        </Column>
     </Group>
```

If you look at the Group element in the sample the field for the 1st and last control are strings. Those in the middle are integers.

The problem is the same work item displays differently in Visual Studio 2015 and using the TFS Web interface. In the Web interface it all looks ok. 
[image: Image from Web UI]

The same data in Visual Studio is practically unreadable.

[image: Image from Visual Studio 2015]

You can't even see the 1st 2 integer fields even if there is data selected. (they are drop downs). It does not appear the VS version is respecting the field or column widths.

Is there any way to fix this?

Is there a way to have field boarders appear in VS?

As requested full wit here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <witd:WITD application="Work item type editor" version="1.0" xmlns:witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef">
<WORKITEMTYPE name="Product Backlog Item">
<DESCRIPTION>Tracks an activity the user will be able to perform with the product.</DESCRIPTION>
<FIELDS>
  <FIELD name="Iteration Path" refname="System.IterationPath" type="TreePath" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Iteration ID" refname="System.IterationId" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="External Link Count" refname="System.ExternalLinkCount" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Team Project" refname="System.TeamProject" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Hyperlink Count" refname="System.HyperLinkCount" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Attached File Count" refname="System.AttachedFileCount" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Node Name" refname="System.NodeName" type="String" />
  <FIELD name="Area Path" refname="System.AreaPath" type="TreePath" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Revised Date" refname="System.RevisedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="detail" />
  <FIELD name="Changed Date" refname="System.ChangedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="ID" refname="System.Id" type="Integer" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Area ID" refname="System.AreaId" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Authorized As" refname="System.AuthorizedAs" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" />
  <FIELD name="Title" refname="System.Title" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <REQUIRED />
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="State" refname="System.State" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Authorized Date" refname="System.AuthorizedDate" type="DateTime" />
  <FIELD name="Watermark" refname="System.Watermark" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Rev" refname="System.Rev" type="Integer" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Changed By" refname="System.ChangedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Reason" refname="System.Reason" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <VALIDUSER />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="[project]\Contributors" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="Work Item Type" refname="System.WorkItemType" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Created Date" refname="System.CreatedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Created By" refname="System.CreatedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Description" refname="System.Description" type="HTML" />
  <FIELD name="History" refname="System.History" type="History" />
  <FIELD name="Related Link Count" refname="System.RelatedLinkCount" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Tags" refname="System.Tags" type="PlainText" />
  <FIELD name="Backlog Priority" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority" type="Double" reportable="detail" />
  <FIELD name="Integration Build" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="&lt;None&gt;" />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="Closed Date" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension">
    <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
      <READONLY />
    </WHENNOTCHANGED>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="Effort" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum" />
  <FIELD name="Acceptance Criteria" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria" type="HTML" />
  <FIELD name="Business Value" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" type="Integer" reportable="measure" formula="sum" />
  <FIELD name="OldSystemObjectID" refname="OldSystem.Common.ObjectId" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="OldSystemFormattedID" refname="OldSystem.Common.FormattedId" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="OldSystemProjectName" refname="OldSystem.Common.Project" type="String" />
  <FIELD name="OldSystemUpdateTime" refname="OldSystem.Common.UpdateTime" type="DateTime" />
  <FIELD name="Support Ticket #" refname="MyCompany.SupportTicket" type="String" reportable="detail" />
  <FIELD name="OldSystemTags" refname="OldSystem.Common.Tags" type="String" />
  <FIELD name="Team" refname="MyCompany.Team" type="String" />
  <FIELD name="SVNLog" refname="MyCompany.SVNLog" type="HTML">
    <READONLY not="MyCompany\RT - SCM" />
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="MajorRelease" refname="MyCompany.MajorRelease" type="Integer" reportable="detail">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="1" />
      <LISTITEM value="10" />
      <LISTITEM value="11" />
      <LISTITEM value="12" />
      <LISTITEM value="13" />
      <LISTITEM value="14" />
      <LISTITEM value="15" />
      <LISTITEM value="16" />
      <LISTITEM value="17" />
      <LISTITEM value="18" />
      <LISTITEM value="19" />
      <LISTITEM value="2" />
      <LISTITEM value="20" />
      <LISTITEM value="21" />
      <LISTITEM value="22" />
      <LISTITEM value="23" />
      <LISTITEM value="24" />
      <LISTITEM value="3" />
      <LISTITEM value="4" />
      <LISTITEM value="5" />
      <LISTITEM value="6" />
      <LISTITEM value="7" />
      <LISTITEM value="8" />
      <LISTITEM value="9" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <WHENNOT field="MyCompany.ReleaseYear" value="">
      <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
      <REQUIRED />
    </WHENNOT>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="Hotfix" refname="MyCompany.Hotfix" type="String" reportable="detail">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="0" />
      <LISTITEM value="1" />
      <LISTITEM value="2" />
      <LISTITEM value="3" />
      <LISTITEM value="4" />
      <LISTITEM value="5" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="HotfixSeverity" refname="MyCompany.HotfixSeverity" type="String" reportable="detail">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="Hot Update" />
      <LISTITEM value="Hotfix" />
      <LISTITEM value="Regulatory" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <WHEN field="MyCompany.HotfixRelease" value="1">
      <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
      <REQUIRED />
    </WHEN>
    <WHEN field="MyCompany.HotfixRelease" value="2">
      <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
      <REQUIRED />
    </WHEN>
    <WHEN field="MyCompany.HotfixRelease" value="3">
      <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
      <REQUIRED />
    </WHEN>
    <WHEN field="MyCompany.HotfixRelease" value="4">
      <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
      <REQUIRED />
    </WHEN>
    <WHEN field="MyCompany.HotfixRelease" value="5">
      <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
      <REQUIRED />
    </WHEN>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="ReleaseYear" refname="MyCompany.ReleaseYear" type="Integer" reportable="detail">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="15" />
      <LISTITEM value="16" />
      <LISTITEM value="17" />
      <LISTITEM value="18" />
      <LISTITEM value="19" />
      <LISTITEM value="20" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="MinorRelease" refname="MyCompany.MinorRelease" type="Integer" reportable="detail">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="0" />
      <LISTITEM value="1" />
      <LISTITEM value="2" />
      <LISTITEM value="3" />
      <LISTITEM value="4" />
      <LISTITEM value="5" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <WHENNOT field="MyCompany.MajorRelease" value="">
      <REQUIRED />
    </WHENNOT>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="HotfixRelease" refname="MyCompany.HotfixRelease" type="Integer" reportable="detail">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="1" />
      <LISTITEM value="2" />
      <LISTITEM value="3" />
      <LISTITEM value="4" />
      <LISTITEM value="5" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
</FIELDS>
<WORKFLOW>
  <STATES>
    <STATE value="Approved">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Committed">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Done">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort">
          <READONLY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue">
          <READONLY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="New">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Removed" />
  </STATES>
  <TRANSITIONS>
    <TRANSITION from="New" to="Done">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Approved" to="Done">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Committed" to="Done">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="New" to="Removed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Removed from the backlog" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Approved" to="Removed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Removed from the backlog" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="" to="New">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="New backlog item" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Done" to="New">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Moved to the backlog" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Removed" to="New">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Reconsidering backlog item" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Approved" to="New">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Moved to the backlog" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Committed" to="New">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Moved to the backlog" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Done" to="Approved">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Additional work found" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="New" to="Approved">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Approved by the Product Owner" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Committed" to="Approved">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Work stopped" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Done" to="Committed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Additional work found" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="New" to="Committed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Commitment made by the team" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Approved" to="Committed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Commitment made by the team" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
  </TRANSITIONS>
</WORKFLOW>
<FORM>
  <Layout HideReadOnlyEmptyFields="true" HideControlBorders="true">
    <Group Margin="(4,0,0,0)">
      <Column PercentWidth="100">
        <Control FieldName="System.Title" Type="FieldControl" ControlFontSize="large" EmptyText="&lt;Enter title here&gt;" LabelPosition="Top" />
      </Column>
    </Group>
    <Group Margin="(10,0,0,0)">
      <Column PercentWidth="100">
        <Control FieldName="System.IterationPath" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" Label="Ite&amp;ration" LabelPosition="Left" />
      </Column>
    </Group>
    <Group Margin="(10,0,0,0)">
      <Column PercentWidth="50">
        <Group Label="Status">
          <Column PercentWidth="100">
            <Control FieldName="System.AssignedTo" Type="FieldControl" Label="Assi&amp;gned To" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control Type="LabelControl" Label="State Order : 1.New 2.Approved 3.Committed 4.Done 5.Removed" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="System.State" Type="FieldControl" Label="Stat&amp;e" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="System.Reason" Type="FieldControl" Label="Reason" LabelPosition="Left" ReadOnly="True" />
            <Group>
              <Column PercentWidth="12">
                <Control Type="LabelControl" Label="Release #" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="5">
                <Control FieldName="MyCompany.ReleaseYear" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" MinimumSize="(0,0)" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="5">
                <Control FieldName="MyCompany.MajorRelease" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" MinimumSize="(0,0)" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="5">
                <Control Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" FieldName="MyCompany.MinorRelease" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="5">
                <Control FieldName="MyCompany.HotfixRelease" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="25">
                <Control FieldName="MyCompany.HotfixSeverity" Type="FieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
            </Group>
          </Column>
        </Group>
      </Column>
      <Column PercentWidth="50">
        <Group Label="Details">
          <Column PercentWidth="100">
            <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" Type="FieldControl" Label="Effort" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" Type="FieldControl" Label="Business Value" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="System.AreaPath" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" Label="&amp;Area" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="MyCompany.SupportTicket" Type="FieldControl" Label="Support Ticket#" LabelPosition="Left" />
          </Column>
        </Group>
      </Column>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <Column PercentWidth="50">
        <TabGroup>
          <Tab Label="Description">
            <Control FieldName="System.Description" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="Storyboards">
            <Control Type="LinksControl" Name="StoryboardsControl" LabelPosition="Top">
              <LinksControlOptions>
                <WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="excludeAll" />
                <ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="include">
                  <Filter LinkType="Storyboard" />
                </ExternalLinkFilters>
                <LinkColumns>
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Title" />
                  <LinkColumn LinkAttribute="System.Links.Comment" />
                </LinkColumns>
              </LinksControlOptions>
            </Control>
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="Test Cases">
            <Control Type="LinksControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" Name="TestedBy">
              <LinksControlOptions>
                <LinkColumns>
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Id" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.WorkItemType" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Title" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.AssignedTo" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.State" />
                </LinkColumns>
                <WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="include">
                  <Filter LinkType="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy" FilterOn="forwardname" />
                </WorkItemLinkFilters>
                <ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="excludeAll" />
                <WorkItemTypeFilters FilterType="include">
                  <Filter WorkItemType="Test Case" />
                </WorkItemTypeFilters>
              </LinksControlOptions>
            </Control>
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="Tasks">
            <Control Type="LinksControl" Name="Hierarchy" Label="" LabelPosition="Top">
              <LinksControlOptions>
                <LinkColumns>
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Id" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Title" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.AssignedTo" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.State" />
                </LinkColumns>
                <WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="include">
                  <Filter LinkType="System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy" FilterOn="forwardname" />
                </WorkItemLinkFilters>
                <ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="excludeAll" />
                <WorkItemTypeFilters FilterType="include">
                  <Filter WorkItemType="Task" />
                </WorkItemTypeFilters>
              </LinksControlOptions>
            </Control>
          </Tab>
        </TabGroup>
      </Column>
      <Column PercentWidth="50">
        <TabGroup Margin="(5,0,0,0)">
          <Tab Label="Acceptance Criteria">
            <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="History">
            <Control FieldName="System.History" Type="WorkItemLogControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="Links">
            <Control Type="LinksControl" Name="GeneralLinks" LabelPosition="Top">
              <LinksControlOptions>
                <LinkColumns>
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Id" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.WorkItemType" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Title" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.AssignedTo" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.State" />
                  <LinkColumn LinkAttribute="System.Links.Comment" />
                </LinkColumns>
                <WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
                <ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
                <WorkItemTypeFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
              </LinksControlOptions>
            </Control>
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="Attachments">
            <Control Type="AttachmentsControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" />
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="Other">
            <Control FieldName="OldSystem.Common.ObjectId" Type="FieldControl" Label="OldSystem Object ID:" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="OldSystem.Common.FormattedId" Type="FieldControl" Label="OldSystem Formatted ID:" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="OldSystem.Common.Project" Type="FieldControl" Label="OldSystem Project:" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="OldSystem.Common.UpdateTime" Type="FieldControl" Label="OldSystem Update Time:" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="OldSystem.Common.Tags" Type="FieldControl" Label="OldSystemTags:" LabelPosition="Left" />
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="SVN Commits">
            <Control FieldName="MyCompany.SVNLog" Type="HtmlFieldControl" LabelPosition="Left" Dock="Fill" />
          </Tab>
        </TabGroup>
      </Column>
    </Group>
  </Layout>
</FORM>
</WORKITEMTYPE>
</witd:WITD>
```

Comment: I don't get anything unexpected with your layout definitions. 1). Do you get another VS2015 to test it? 2). Can you share the WIT definition file you used?

Comment: I see this behavior on multiple PC with VS2015 and I also see it on VS2013. Also If there are are values in the fields which were entered in Web UI the VS display shows fields. It is only when there are no values (as when it is a new work item) that Web UI does not display correctly.

Comment: And before you ask. The fields in question are type Integer. zero is not a valid default value so it is not in the list of valid values. We want for force the user to set the values.